# Хранение важных данных в переменных flask

Tags: безопасность, flask

У меня есть некоторые важные константные данные, которые надо где-то хранить. Самое первое что приходит в голову - хранить их в переменных прямо в приложении Flask.

Читая информацию по этой теме, я натыкался на статьи, где говорится что это небезопасно и, что лучше хранить данные в базах данных. Но,  там  не приводят никаких примеров. Я новичок в теме информационной безопасности, поэтому не знаю точного ответа.

Как же все-таки лучше поступить?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/346306/

Comment: О каких константных данных речь? В чём их важность и константность? Почему вы решили, что говорения про небезопасность относятся к вашему случаю?

Comment: @andreymal под константными данными я имею ввиду данные, которые запишутся один раз,и будут использоваться во всей программе в данном виде. важность их в том - что это куки бота, который будет делать запросы и получать информацию (без бота там не обойтись т.к доступ только для участников). как я описал в вопросе, я вычитал информацию,что, держать важные данные в переменных - небезопасно.

Comment: @PythonNewbie держать важные данные в переменных небезопасно тогда, когда их может прочитать кто угодно. В общем случае это не так, а значит безопасно. К тому же, если подразумеваются постоянные запросы к какому-то сервису с этими куками, то держать куки в переменной неизбежно придётся (хотя бы временно) и других вариантов просто не существует. Только лучше эту переменную читать из отдельного файла или из базы данных, чтобы в коде на виду не болталась